# Using puppeteer as a semi-automated system

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

I've got a certain task which I would normally accomplish with a chrome extension.

The only thing I cannot perform with a chrome extension is to make a screenshot of a node. I've been trying to use `debugger` api, but I couldn't make it snap a proper screenshot of an element when it goes beyond the viewport (even using the `captureBeyondViewport` property and some other stuff).

So my goal right now is to make puppeteer a semi-automated tool. It should open a browser and work in a concept similar to chrome extensions. So I have to be able to run certain code on any of the tabs of the puppeteer browser instance. Just like content scripts do. Once something happens (for example, clicking on certain element) the puppeteer should make certain actions (eg make a screenshot of the node/full-page screenshot etc). It must be able to cover multiple tabs and perform an action only from the tab where the action was performed.

If anyone can give me a good option to test with the chrome extension, that would be even better. The goal is to be able to capture screenshot of an element even if it's big enough to go beyond the viewport.

PS: html2canvas isn't an option because the website I need to work on the screenshots lack of images and basically look a bit weird.

Comment: @wOxxOm would be glad to hear your thoughts.

Comment: @Xan yours as well.

Comment: Everything you stated above is possible with puppeteer except clicking on live website. You will need some way around to pass data to the puppeteer. Note that puppeteer also requires to work on node environment, not on browser like chrome extension.

Comment: @TendyTeslo yep, that is the question - I have to keep track of some events (my custom handlers) and do something on a proper tab (so I have to know when the user opens a new tab or navigates on existing and load my event handler again if needed).
I had a thought of having an extension installed inside puppeteer instance. I know they only support background pages, but that should be enough if the content scripts will work and will be able to pass data to background script and the background script would communicate with puppeteer.

Comment: I also have to know which tab is active or be able to get to the tab (from puppeteer) by tabId (which I could know from my chrome extension).

Comment: OK. One possible way is to start the Puppeteer instance with Express or any other Node server then call it from your extension.  This way you can provide your Screen Shot options within its params.

Comment: @TendyTeslo ya, I thought about this, it was actually my initial thought. I didn't yet try it, but there was one question in my head - how would I pass/define the tab which should be screenshotted? Is there a way to use a tabId inside puppeteer if I get it from chrome extension? If not, I think I should make a loop which would ping each page and get if this page must be screenshotted (for example, we could add some class to the body). But this seems as a workaround, not a normal way.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can store the Tab page as constant or variable. E.G:  const myPage = await browser.newPage();. After this you have your page const to things like: myPage.evaluate() // To run code on the page OR myPage.screenshot(). Go ahead and give it a try.

Comment: @TendyTeslo as I stated, I need a semi-automated system. Let me provide a more simple example. So there won't be any newPage()'s, but instead the user will browse through the tabs just like he normally does. Then at some point the user clicks on the extension icon and I would like to make a screenshot of the tab (using puppeteer) from where the extension icon was clicked.